# Showing that the GCD of two expression multiplied by n, for any n

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Can you please help me with this question:

> Show that the gcd of $8n+7$ and $7n+6$ is $1$, where $n$ is a positive integer.

Thank you.

Comment: Whoa...slow down a bit! You've asked (posted) five questions in the last hour. *Take your time* to read the answers, think about, and digest solutions and hints. If you tackle some of your earlier questions, it may help answer other questions you have.

Answer (score 5):

Simply: $(8n+7)\cdot 7 - (7n+6)\cdot 8 = 1$

More generally, if $ad-bc=\pm 1$ then $\gcd(an+b,cn+d)=1$ for all integers $n$.

This is not necessary however, since $\gcd(an+0,an+1)=1$.

Comment: Sir, you are a cheat.

Comment: @vonbrand: Clever, rather.

Comment: The neat thing is that if you had $an+b$ and $cn+d$ then this trick would work exactly when $ad-bc=\pm 1$ - that's the determinant of a $2\times 2$ matrix. What happens when $ad-bc\neq \pm 1$?

Comment: @vonbrand: Don't worry, I don't take offense. I essentially did the same work you did in your answer, then I hid it all in this one-line conclusion, which is definitely cheating of a sort. :)

Answer (score 2):

Apply Euclid's algorithm:

$(8 n + 7) : (7 n + 6) = 1, \text{ remainder } n + 1$

$(7 n + 6) : (n + 1) = 7, \text{ remainder } -1$

So $\gcd(8 n + 7, 7 n + 6) = 1$ (it must divide $-1$ and be positive)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\rm\:d\:$ divides both $\rm\:7+8n,\, 6+7n\:$ then *eliminating* $\rm\:n\:$ shows $\rm\:d\:$ divides an *integer*

$\begin{eqnarray} &&\rm   \ &\rm\ j\,d& &\!=&\rm 7\,+\,\color{#0A0}8\,n\quad  [1] \\ &&\rm &\rm k\,d& &\!=&\rm 6\,+\,\color{#C00}7\,n\quad [2]\\
\quad\color{#C00}7[1]\!-\!\color{#0A0}8[2]\:\Rightarrow\!\! &&\rm (7j\!-\!8k)\!\!\!\!\!&\rm\ \ \ d& &\!=&\rm  7(7)\!-\!8(6) = 1\:\Rightarrow\: d\mid 1
\end{eqnarray}$